# How do I extract XML tags similar to XPATH with the XmlSlurper API in Java?

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

I am able to traverse the XML tree by importing the XmlSlurper API, but how do I extract specific tags from the XML like with XPATH?  I want to extract them using the XmlSlurper API in Java in a way similar to the question [How to apply predicate to GPath when I am using XMLSlurper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188439/how-to-apply-predicate-to-gpath-when-i-am-using-xmlslurper) asked for parsing in Groovy.

I have tried using the find command without success, and when Googling haven't found any examples on the syntax to specify the path when using the API inside of Java.